# Run command from PHP, exit script, but keep command running

Tags: php, shell

I am running a PHP script that uses the `passthru` function to run system commands in the background. By redirecting the output and putting the `&` at the end of the command, the script is able to continue executing without waiting for the system command to finish. However, the PHP script itself does not exit until all commands are complete. Is there a way that the PHP script can start a system command and then not have to wait for that command to finish before exiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using nohup?

Instead of

```
my_command >/dev/null &
```

do

```
nohup mycommand >/dev/null &
```

Comment: Even with nohup, the PHP script will not exit until the system command is finished, although the rest of the script has completed.